# Excel VBA, range.value = range.value, unexpected results

Tags: vba, excel

hopefully someone would be kind enough to point out why this isn't working. Basically via vba a new line is inserted @ the last row of a table (Row41), this pushes the last line down (creating a gap within the data) then the last line values are transferred up one row so the blank row is at the bottom.

Now the process works fine except for two of the cell values change randomly, below are the before and after

Before:

- Cell(41,B) = 03/10/14
- Cell(41,C) = 12345
- Cell(41,E) = 3.00
- Cell(41,F) = DD

After:

- Cell(41,B) = 03/10/14
- Cell(41,C) = 12345
- Cell(41,E) = 41915
- Cell(41,F) = 41915

I've double checked the set ranges and they are as they should be, any ideas? Oh for the code the Specific_Tbl variable is 2

```
    '[Capture table First/Last row number]
    int_FirstRow = .Cells(4, "AC").Offset(0, Specific_Tbl)
    int_LastRow = .Cells(6, "AC").Offset(0, Specific_Tbl)

    '[Insert Blank Row]
    .Range("A" & int_LastRow & ":Z" & int_LastRow).Insert shift:=xlDown

    '[Set Cell Ranges]
    Select Case Specific_Tbl
        Case 1
            '[Remerge Description]
            .Range(.Cells(int_LastRow, "E"), .Cells(int_LastRow, "H")).MergeCells = True
            Set rng_Tmp1 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow & ":C" & int_LastRow & ",E" & int_LastRow & ":J" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp2 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":C" & int_LastRow + 1 & ",E" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":J" & int_LastRow + 1)
        Case 2, 3
            Set rng_Tmp1 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow & ":C" & int_LastRow & ",E" & int_LastRow & ":F" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp2 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":C" & int_LastRow + 1 & ",E" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":F" & int_LastRow + 1)
    End Select

    '[Transfer values and clear]
    rng_Tmp1.Value = rng_Tmp2.Value
    rng_Tmp2.ClearContents
```

Comment: Have you set any break points and stepped through the code?

Comment: Hi PJ, yeah stepped through and everything works as expected until the rng_Tmp1.value = rng_Tmp2.value

Comment: Hi pnuts, thanks i did think it was coming from the date but i dont understand why

Comment: Thanks PJ, it doesn't matter whether its gone through case 1,2 or 3 then results are the same. At the point of value = value the ranges are correct, i've checked via the immediate window rng_Tmp1 = $B$41:$C$41,$E$41:$F$41, rng_Tmp2 =$B$42:$C$42,$E$42:$F$42.    And pnuts is right its definitely the date from column B being put into columns E & F, I just don't understand why.

Comment: Perhaps doing a split range value = value just doesn't work even if the ranges are exactly the same.

Comment: @Richard ,Maybe you should break those ranges down into smaller sets, instead of trying to get all of it in one go.

Comment: yeah guess I will, thanks for your input, yours too pnuts. I know this issue was never end of the world, just annoying lol, thanks again

Comment: Personally, I find breaking my ideas down to single cell manipulation with loops to be easier.  I can just think along those lines easier than ranges.

Comment: Why are you inserting the row before the last row of the table and not after the last row? Is it because you have totals and you want them to include the new row? Why not use ListObjects - the totals will automatically include the new row.

Comment: @PJRosenburg, totally agree, I was just trying to make the code more efficient.

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers, unfortunately the table in question isn't actually undefined as a table, done like this for cosmetics I believe, I'm building on old work. Perhaps that is something to change in the future, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I never discovered why excel vba was unable to deal with the split range like I believed it would. A workaround was done by adding more range variables to deal with each side of the split range.

```
    '[Capture table First/Last row number]
    int_FirstRow = .Cells(4, "AC").Offset(0, Specific_Tbl)
    int_LastRow = .Cells(6, "AC").Offset(0, Specific_Tbl)

    '[Insert Blank Row]
    .Range("A" & int_LastRow & ":Z" & int_LastRow).Insert shift:=xlDown

    '[Set Cell Ranges]
    Select Case Specific_Tbl
        Case 1
            '[Remerge Description]
            .Range(.Cells(int_LastRow, "E"), .Cells(int_LastRow, "H")).MergeCells = True
            Set rng_Tmp1 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow & ":C" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp2 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":C" & int_LastRow + 1)
            Set rng_Tmp3 = .Range("E" & int_LastRow & ":J" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp4 = .Range("E" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":J" & int_LastRow + 1)
        Case 2, 3
            Set rng_Tmp1 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow & ":C" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp2 = .Range("B" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":C" & int_LastRow + 1)
            Set rng_Tmp3 = .Range("E" & int_LastRow & ":F" & int_LastRow)
            Set rng_Tmp4 = .Range("E" & int_LastRow + 1 & ":F" & int_LastRow + 1)
    End Select

    '[Transfer values and clear]
    rng_Tmp1.Value = rng_Tmp2.Value
    rng_Tmp3.Value = rng_Tmp4.Value
    rng_Tmp2.ClearContents
    rng_Tmp4.ClearContents
```